# limit() isn't working for me in when using find()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, find, limit

I am new to MongoDB and Meteor.js and was trying to check if a document existed in a collection.

I know that I can use `findOne` or `find({condition}).count()`, but an article [here](http://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) made a point that it would be faster to use:

```
find({condition}).limit(1).size().
```

When I use something like

```
PlayersList.find({'name':"Bill"}).limit(1).size()
```

where `PlayersList` is a collection, I get an error saying: **"TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'PlayersList.find({'name':playerName}).limit(1)')"**

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How about using `db.PlayersList.find({'name':"Bill"}).limit(1).size() `?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, no, it won't work. My collection's name is `PlayersList`, like `PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players')`, not `db.PlayersList`. The answer below is almost right (see comment below the answer by Bayesian).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MiniMongo API implemented in Metor is not the same as the Mongo API implemented in the Mongo Shell. In your case, the limit function is not implemented in the MeteorJS "minimongo" cursor binding.   Instead put the limit in the options of the find function.

Posts.find({name:"Bill"}, {limit:1}).count()

Take a look at  http://docs.meteor.com/#find and read about the find function options.

Comment: Thanks, putting `limit` in the `find` function's options is right, however `size()` function will cause an error as it is actually not defined for **cursor** (`find` function returns a **cursor** object). `count()` function should be applied here according to the documentation (http://docs.meteor.com/#count), so I edited your response @Bayesian. The statement should look like: `PlayersList.find({name:"Bill"},{limit:1}).count()` for Meteor.js. I was using MongoDb references without realizing that Meteor has a different API for MongoDb. Thanks again.